# Automatically select last user on login screen ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome

I don't want to select a user each time my computer boots. How can I setup the same behavior as in previous versions of Ubuntu: I need to see password prompt for the last user directly after boot, without Enter.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to install a different login manager.

For example, SDDM - the login manager for KDE does what you want it to do: it will automatically select the previous user and will focus the password entry so you can just type your password and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to log in - with no additional clicking needed.

Comment: There should be a better way then install a different login manager.

Comment: @antibus - if the software that you use doesn't offer a feature, you either have to replace the software or not use the feature. The current version of GDM (which is what Ubuntu ships) **does not support** pre-selecting the last user. SDDM does.

Comment: The other option - which I'm pretty sure you won't think is better - is for you to change GDM source code to have that feature and then try to convince GNOME developers to adopt it. Good luck 

Comment: Yeah sure, but couldn't imagine, such basic feature is not supported by GDM. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Some documentation for GDM configuration can be found here: https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.customizing-graphical-interface.html . The man page points at `/usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas` for a list of possible configuration values. Nothing seems relevant to the original question. Sorry.

Comment: thx for your help.